# Javascript: Get Hi-res fotos from drive and from webcam, draw them on 480x270 canvas, then save hi-res in database

Tags: javascript

Task is to add fotos from drive and webcam with preview in canvas (may be there is another way?) to webpage and database. I use canvas because later i'll need to add stickers to fotos.
I can add fotos to canvas from webcam:

```
const videoSrc = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {
            width: { ideal: 1280 },
            height: { ideal: 720 }
}});

canvasContext.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 1280, 720, 0, 0, 480, 270);
```

and from drive:

```
let file = files[0];
 var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = e.target.result;
        img.onload = function () {
            var height = this.height;
            var width = this.width;
            canvasContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, 480, 270);
        }
    };
```

and then i'd like to save foto with its real height and width to my database

```
let fileUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
```

but when i successfully got foto in database it is 480x270 resolution.
Any ways to solve my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas is basically just another image with some fancy ways to draw to it. So when you create a canvas that is 480x270, you cannot get a higher resolution version from that canvas again.

Instead you should create a canvas with the same resolution as the image and then change the size of the canvas to 480x270 using CSS.

Only problem will be when the aspect ratios of the canvas resolution and the element size don't match. The canvas will probably look stretched.